# search results webpart after render

Tags: javascript, search

I have a search results web part and after moving from one page to the other page (paging button) I need to run some JavaScript code to set some data.

The question is how can I hook up my JavaScript on the after `_spBodyOnHashChange` or somewhere after the `$getClientControl(this).page(11);return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event);` so after the paging button has been clicked and the template has done rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the OOTB `Control_SearchResults.html` control template. In the template, you will find below HTML:

```
<div id="Control_SearchResults">
<!--#_
if (Srch.U.shouldAnimate(ctx.DataProvider)){
Srch.U.hideElement(ctx.ClientControl.get_element());
ctx.OnPostRender = function(){ Srch.U.animateResults(ctx.ClientControl, ctx.DataProvider.get_userAction()); };
}
_#-->
```

In my case, I had a requirement to scroll to top after pagination, so I modified it as below:

```
<div id="Control_SearchResults">
<!--#_
//scroll to top on redraw(pagination, refiner, search)
ctx.ClientControl.set_scrollToTopOnRedraw(true);
if (Srch.U.shouldAnimate(ctx.DataProvider)){
Srch.U.hideElement(ctx.ClientControl.get_element());
ctx.OnPostRender = function(){ Srch.U.animateResults(ctx.ClientControl, ctx.DataProvider.get_userAction()); };
}
_#-->
```

So, you can also customize it as per your requirement and add any javascript function or html here.

Reference - [Scroll to Top Search Result Page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33556.sharepoint-2013-scroll-to-top-search-result-page-ootb-functionality-has-stopped-working.aspx)